# BSC Public RPC Nodes limit per seconds

Tags: web3js, bsc, bscscan

Using [web3.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3) with any of [public RPC Nodes](https://docs.bscscan.com/misc-tools-and-utilities/public-rpc-nodes) I often get "Error: Returned error: limit exceeded" on `getPastEvents`. What is limit in this case? Did I exceed API request limit, or is it something related with block number? Thanks.

```
const contract = new WEB3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(AbiString), ContractID);

const blockNumber = await WEB3.eth.getBlockNumber();

const events = await contract.getPastEvents("allEvents", { fromBlock: blockNumber - 250, toBlock: blockNumber});
```

Comment: Usually public nodes have limits to preserve resources, or prevent certain attacks.

Comment: Any solution on this? We have started to receive same error 2 days ago out of nowhere.

Comment: I believe they recently turned off this ability. Entirely. The limit is zero. You're supposed to run your own node or hire someone else's.